# Lag function usage within a dplyr subset

Tags: r

My basic goal is to subset a data set, and summarise with new columns that use the lag function. I understand how to subset and the data set, but am struggling to complete using the lag function within my data set and that is giving me trouble.

I have already tried a few different ways of implementing it, but have been unsuccessful.

```
gapminder %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(prevPeriod = lag(year),
            lifeExpGrowth = lag(lifeExp),
            popGrowth = lag(pop),
            gdppcGrowth = 100*(gdpPercap/lag(gdpPercap) - 1)))
```

I am currently getting my code to run a lag based upon the country, not the year. the gdppcGrowth is supposed to return a percent as well and I am getting an error;

```
Column `gdppcGrowth` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 12
```

For each of the functions, I want to analyze the data by country focusing on growth rates. I want to use the lag(x) function to access the previous value of a series or vector so that 100*(x/lag(x) - 1) computes standard (arithmetic) growth rates of x expressed as a percent.

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you're trying to do?  `lag()` returns a lagged vector - it isn't used to summarise values.

Comment: I added an edit at the bottom with a bit more instruction for my goal with the lag.

Comment: Perhaps you want `mutate` and not `summarise`.